# how to know what the id of the image which i click in it

Tags: android, imageview

i have this image view ,,

[image]

and this image is change by recycler view which have many image ,, the question is  how to know which image i click ! and i have a integer value to add it to for loop any idea ??

this is the code of this activity

```
public class ListViewDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView AppImage;
TextView AppName,AppArtist,AppContentType,AppRights,AppCategory,AppRealseDate,AppSammary;
ImageButton AppLink;
Context context;
public ListViewDetailsFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view_details, container, false);}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppImage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    AppName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textname);
    AppArtist = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textartest);
    AppContentType = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textcontent);
    AppRights = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textrights);
    AppCategory = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textCategory);
    AppRealseDate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textRelease);
    AppSammary = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textSummary);
    AppLink = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    String name = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_name");
    final String image = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_image");
    String artist = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_artist");
    String contentType = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_ContentType");
    String rights = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_Rights");
    String category = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_Category");
    String realse = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_ReleaseDate");
    final String link = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_link");
    String sammary = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_summary");
    AppName.setText(name);
    final AppShowModule appShowModule = new AppShowModule();

    AppArtist.setText(artist);
    AppContentType.setText(contentType);
    AppRights.setText(rights);
    AppCategory.setText(category);
    AppRealseDate.setText(realse);
    AppSammary.setText(sammary);
    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(AppImage);
    AppLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AppImage.setTag("id that you get from extras");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    WebView.class);
            intent.putExtra("App_link", link);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);}});
    AppImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), ImageList.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }});}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set an OnClickListener (in your adapter) for every ImageView of your RecyclerView in your `onCreateViewHolder` method.

You can get the position for your item by using `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: thank you @ZShock for you answer my problem is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456214/error-when-parsing-jsonarray-include-another-jsonarray)  with all details please check it and tell me in which adapter i will but this ?